# Property 'size' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, file

In my typescript project, I have a list of files coming from an input, I am trying run through a loop in typescript to check if there is any file exceeds the limit,

```
const allowSize = 104857600; // 100mb
const files = event.target.files;
const hasInValidFileSize = Array.from(files).filter(
    (item) => allowSize < item.size // Error line
  );
```

The functionality is working fine, but In console its giving me a build error.
`TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

Please help me to fix

Comment: Most likely your `event.target.files` is inferred to `any`, so `Array.from(files)` is inferred to `unknown[]`. You need to provide correct type for `event.target.files`.

Answer (score 1):

The event.target is unknown to Typescript, you should assign a type to it. I don't know the proper context of the code but something like this perhaps.

```
document.querySelector('#test')?.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const allowSize = 104857600; // 100mb
    const files = (<HTMLInputElement>event?.target)?.files;
    if (!files) return;
    
    const hasInValidFileSize = Array.from(files).filter(
        (item) => allowSize < item.size // No more error
    );

    return hasInValidFileSize;
})
```

Notice the

```
(<HTMLInputElement>event?.target)?.files
```

Since files is a property of HTMLInputElement we can cast the event.target to this type and then request files on it, ? marks are potential undefined/empty values.

EDIT:
It is not clear where your code resides thus Im offering a different style of writing to prevent JSX parsing the type declaration as an HTML element with a missing closing tag.

```
(event?.target as HTMLInputElement)?.files
```

Comment: I tried your solution, its says `JSX element 'HTMLInputElement' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)`

Comment: @MuhammadOwais I have no idea of further context in your code, this is the right way to write it in pure Typescript, I guess you are using React or something? You need to adapt your code so that React can parse <HTMLInputElement> without thinking its an actual html node, since its a TS type declaration..

Comment: @MuhammadOwais You could also write it as `(event?.target as HTMLInputElement)?.files`

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by just adding `(: any)`

```
const files = event.target.files;
const hasInValidFileSize = Array.from(files).filter(
    (item: any) => allowSize < item.size
);
`
```

Comment: With this you are basically ignoring the main point of Typescript and that is declaring proper types, this is not the best practice just an fyi. You need to be able to validate the input items.